# Can you submit Docker images as jobs to Spark

Tags: apache-spark

The title. I checked docs and found [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#docker-images) but it's unclear what it's designed to do. There's mention of using Docker's Spark images at the end.

I know that you can submit Jars, Python jobs etc. but I was wondering if Docker images are an option.